# React Functional Component Correct Props Usage

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, react-props

There are raw props data and I want to add some value to use in functional component. What is the best practice to achieve that? There is a sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-curran-x691c?file=/src/App.js:731-1036

**Q1:** (In Child 1) Does setting props to state (even if alter the data to render) anti-pattern and causes two times re-rendering(which can be negligible)?

**Q2:** (In Child 2) It seems OK but it causes unnecesary iteration for each render even if the other state changes would it be OK for small arrays or not a good practice?

**Q3:** I encounter with this case in too many times especially when using redux. What is the best practice?

I try to explain what I mean;
Lets one of the props is `bigArr`.This is the parent that I will use:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [bigArr, setBigArr] = React.useState(["foo", "bar", "kata"]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Child1 data={bigArr} />
      <Child2 data={bigArr} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Child 1**
Practice one;

```
const Child1 = (props) => {
  const [tempArr, setTempArr] = React.useState([]);
  const [showData, setShowData] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const newData = props.data.map((element) => {
      return element + " child1";
    });
    setTempArr(newData);
  }, [props.data]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Child1</h1>
      {showData && tempArr.map((el) => <div>{el}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Child 2**
Practice two;

```
const Child2 = (props) => {
  const [showData, setShowData] = React.useState(true);
  const tempArr = props.data.map((element) => {
    return element + " child2";
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Child2</h1>
      {showData && tempArr.map((el) => <div>{el}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
};
```